# Ping through GRE tunnel discarded between 2 interfaces of a router - Ping does not reach subnet

Tags: linux, routing, iptables, tunnel

I have an interesting issue that I hope someone can help with. I am trying to create a GRE tunnel between 2 routers (running Linux Ubuntu 12.04) and pass traffic between 2 subnets trough this tunnel.

What I am trying to achieve can be simplified by the following setup, imagine 4 computers (as the following diagram will show), 2 are routers, 2 are PCs connected to a gateway...

```
      |----------------------|              |----------------------|
SUBA--+--ETH0          ETH1--+----------- --+--ETH0          ETH1--+--SUBB
      |----------------------|              |----------------------|
            PC1 as router                        PC2 as router
```

Now if the diagram is looking wrong, let me explain it.
I have 2 PC's configured as routers (`ip_forwarding=1, proxy_arp=1`). Each PC as router has 2 interfaces and each interface has its own ip.

Left side of the diagram (PC1 as router)

- `SUBA=192.165.13.25`
- ETH0 on PC1 as router `=192.165.13.254` (GW of SUBA)
- ETH1 on PC1 as router `= 192.168.6.40` (address as provided by service provider) -> this is the default GW of the PC1 as router.

Right side of the diagram (PC2 as router)

- `SUBB=192.160.20.25`
- ETH0 on PC2 as router `=192.168.20.41` (address as provided by service provider)
- ETH1 on PC2 as router `=192.160.20.254` (GW of SUBB)

The routing is pretty simple on each end and can be described by words.

On PC1 as router:

- to access 192.165.13.0/24 use eth0
- to access 192.168.6.0/24 use eth1
- default GW is 192.168.6.40 => this is eth1

On PC2 as router:

- to access 192.160.20.0/24 use eth1
- to access 192.168.20.0/24 use eth0
- default GW is 192.168.20.41 => this is eth0

In this setup, WITHOUT ANY ADDITIONAL IPTABLES RULES, everyone can ping everyone. And I am good. SUBA can ping SUBB and the other way around is also okay.

Now I am creating a GRE tunnel between PC1 as router eth1 and PC2 as router eth0
tunnel on PC1 as router has GRE tunnel with local = `192.168.6.40` and remote = `192.168.20.41`
and of course I have the symmetry on the other router with tunnel on PC2 as router has GRE tunnel with local = `192.168.20.41` and remote = `192.168.6.40`...

I modify the routing (add one rule) on PC2 as router just to force traffic into the tunnel:
to access `192.165.13.0/24` use the GRE tunnel.

Nothing else is done.

Now SUBB is trying to ping SUBA and it does not work, does not work either trying to ping the GW of SUBA (which is the second interface of PC1 as router)

Here is what I see using wireshark or tcpdump:

1. Traffic gets in the tunnel interface on PC2 as router
2. Traffic gets out of the tunnel interface on PC1 as router
3. Traffic never gets to the eth0 interface of PC1 as router.

So I dug deeper and added several rules in the IP tables to see what was happening:

each ping request is counted in:

```
mangle prerouting
nat prerouting
```

But ping is not counted in neither mangle forward (if trying to forward to SUBA) or mangle input.
It seems that the kernel silently discard the packet in the routing and I have no idea why. In my opinion, I should not have to modify iptables as I did not need to before the GRE tables was created...

Any help on what might be happening, how to get the kernel to report the packet or the reason of why it is discarded would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you assign ip addresses to the tunnel endpoints on both PC1 and PC2 ? If yes, and if the tunnel endpoints ip addresses are x.x.x.1 and x.x.x.2, can you ping from .1 to .2 ?

Comment: Can you please post your routing tables on PC1 and PC2?

Comment: I have the same problem, help someone